# How to send PUT and DELETE when JavaScript is disable from your browsers?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, rest

How are you going to send REST's action words to the server if **javascript** is **disable** from your browser?

Below is my simple test for sending RESTful verbs to the server. It tightly relies on ajax's `type: 'GET', etc`.

jquery,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

     $(".rest-get").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'server.php',
            dataType: "json", // data type of response
            success: function(){
                //
            }
        });
         return false;
     });

     $(".rest-post").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'server.php',
            dataType: "json", // data type of response
            success: function(){
                //
            }
        });
         return false;
     });

     $(".rest-put").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: 'server.php',
            dataType: "json", // data type of response
            success: function(){
                //
            }
        });
         return false;
     });

     $(".rest-delete").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: 'server.php',
            dataType: "json", // data type of response
            success: function(){
                //
            }
        });
         return false;
     });

});
```

html,

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="rest-get">Get</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="rest-post">Post</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="rest-put">Put</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="rest-delete">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

php,

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];?> // you get PUT, DELETE, GET, or POST
```

I know we can send POST from html's form,

```
<form method="POST">
...
</form>
```

But what about **PUT** and **DELETE**? If there is no way to send them from HTML's form, then your webservice or API would fail when the javascript is killed off the browsers then?

Comment: you can put whatever method you want into the form's method. and if JS is disabled, that'll be the ONLY way you could even try to do a put/delete on the server.

Comment: If JS is disabled, you can't use AJAX. You can only use ordinary links and form submission. You'll need to put the REST client on the server.

Comment: thanks. you mean we can do this - `<form method="PUT">`??

Comment: How do you `put the REST client on the server`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `POST` but in addition send the following:

PUT

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
```

DELETE

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"/>
```

Comment: Not supported, at least not according to specs. Some browsers might support that anyway, but they probably shouldn't. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-in-html-forms

Answer (score 1):

There is sadly no standard way to do it with a `<form>` tag.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1

Answer (score 1):

HTML forms only support GET and POST due to various reasons relating to caching, whether or not it's safe to repeat failed requests, etc (PUT and DELETE support were in a HTML 5 draft, but dropped for these reasons).

It could be possible to work around these by using a hidden field in the form to specify the actual method, and then look for that field on the server.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="actualMethod" value="PUT" />
</form>
```

On the server you'd have something along the lines of:

```
$formMethod = isset ($_POST ['actualMethod'])? $_POST ['actualMethod']: $_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'];

switch ($formMethod) {
    case "PUT":
        // ...
```

Of course there's a lot of limitations to using this trick, but it should suffice for simpler cases.